# Django : input field dropdown for receiver customized based on sender

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to make my dropdown list for the receiver in which the sender's id/name won't be included. I guess this is not a case of chained dropdown which has been answered previously. Maybe ajax is needed to be used here, but I am not understanding the exact code of ajax, if it is to be used. Below are my template file, views.py file and models.py file.

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Bank_App/css/styles.css' %}" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

    

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <center>
            <h2>Customer Details</h2>
        </center>


        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Sr. No.</th>
                <th>Customer Id</th>
                <th>Customer Email</th>
                <th>Account Balance</th>
                <th>Send Money</th>
            </tr>
            {% for customer in customer_details %}
            <tr>
                <td id="customer_pk">{{customer.pk}}</td>
                <td id="customer_id">{{customer.customer_id}}</td>
                <td id="customer_email">{{customer.customer_id.email}}</td>
                <td id="customer_acc_balance">{{customer.account_balance}}</td>
               
                <td>                    
                    <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnDemo" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            data-bs-target="#exampleModal" id="send" data-name={{customer.customer_id}}
                            data-balance={{customer.account_balance}}>
                            Send Money
                        </button>
                    </center>

                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Transfer Money</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h6 id="modal_body"></h6>
                    <center>
                        <form id="transfer-money-form">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <label for="senderId">Sender Id :</label>                            
                            <b><input type="text" id="senderId" name="senderId" disabled></b><br>
                            Account Balance : <b><span id="account_bal" name="account_bal"></b></span><br><br>

                            <div class="input-group mb-3">

                                <label for="receiverId">Receiver Id :</label>


                                <select class="form-select d-md-inline" id="receiverId">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected hidden></option>
                                    {% for i in customer_details %}
                                    <option value="{{i.customer_id}}">{{i.customer_id}}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}                                    
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            Amount : <span><input type="number" step="0.01" min=0 id="amt_transfer"></span>                           

                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#exampleModal" id="submit" value="SUBMIT">
                                    Submit
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </center>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.btnDemo').click(function () {    
            senderID = $(this).data('name');
            $('#senderId').val(senderID);        
            $('#account_bal').html($(this).data('balance'));
            
            
        });        

        $(document).on('submit', '#transfer-money-form', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();    
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/transaction',
                data: {
                    sender_id: $('#senderId').val(),
                    receiver_id: $('#receiverId').val(),
                    amt_transfer: $('#amt_transfer').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },
                success: function () {
                    alert("Transaction done!");
                    console.log("this ran!");
                }    
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>    
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, request
from . models import Customer_Detail, Transaction
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context = {
        'customer_details': Customer_Detail.objects.all()
    }
    
    return render(request, 'Bank_App/home.html',context)


def transaction(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        senderId = request.POST['sender_id']
        print(senderId)        
        receiverId = request.POST.get('receiver_id')
        print(receiverId)
        amt_transfer = request.POST['amt_transfer']

    Transaction.objects.create(
        sender_id = senderId,
        reciever_id = receiverId,
        amt_transfer = amt_transfer
    )
     
    return HttpResponse('')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer_Detail(models.Model):  
    
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    account_balance = models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self) :
        return self.customer_id.email



class Transaction(models.Model):      
    sender_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reciever_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    amt_transfer = models.FloatField()
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)    
    
    def __str__(self) :
        return str(self.pk)
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#receiverId option").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.show();
});
$("#opt-" + senderID).hide();
});
```

This solved the issue. One more thing just added the id with option tags

```
<option id="opt-{{i.customer_id}}" value="{{i.customer_id}}">{{i.customer_id}}</option>
```